# jquery .next() skips selected elements separated by <br> tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why doesn't Jquery's .next() function return the next selected item when those items are separated by `<br>` tags?

Here's some code taken from the JQueryUI website demo area:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "button:first" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
      },
      text: false
    }).next().button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
      }
    }).next().button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-gear",
        secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
      }
    }).next().button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-gear",
        secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
      },
      text: false
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Button with icon only</button>
<button>Button with icon on the left</button>
<button>Button with two icons</button>
<button>Button with two icons and no text</button>


</body> 
</html>
```

This results in a display like:

[image: Correct display]

But if I insert a `<br>` tag after the first   element, then the next  .button() call is skipped resulting in the following display:

[image: Incorrect display]

The second .next().button( ... "ui-icon-locked" ...) function seems to be skipped and the rest of the .next().button() functions are off-by-one.

I can fix this by using IDs, creating a buttonset and styling it and I'm sure there are other ways too, but is there something about JQuery selections and `<br>` tags that I am missing here?

Comment: because the `<br>` **is** the next item. giving the method a selector won't change that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.next()` always return the very next element. Passing a parameter to this function is only a "condition". If the condition isnt met, the jQuery object will be empty.

You can use `.nextAll()` with `:first` to counter this:

```
 $('button:first').button(...).nextAll('button:first') //and on and on
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer as well as providing a solution. I can see how I misread the .next() documentation now.